# Error with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Tags: python, pip

I'm going through the Python Crash Course book and I'm on the section on deploying my app to Heroku. When trying to create the requirements.txt file, I get this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I'm on windows and using the venv module. Running the command from the command prompt.

Comment: In your title you have "requirements .txt" with a space before ".txt". Do you have that space when running `pip freeze` as well?

Comment: Oops, just edited the title. But nope, i don't have the space when running it.

Comment: Running pip freeze on its own works fine and returns the package names, also running ‘echo test > test.txt’ works. So I'm not sure where the disconnect is.

Comment: Can you [edit] provide more info about your env? (What is your OS? What is your Python env? Where are you running the command from?)

Comment: @GinoMempin I'm on windows and using the venv module. Running the command from the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Double quote is not required .and put >> instead of > .

Comment: Thanks @vishal! Creating the txt file and using the double `>>` works. I'm not sure why the single `>` had issues though.

Comment: "*`>>` is for overwriting the file and `>` is for appending the file if exists*". Exactly opposite.